# Angular5 Getting undefined values on <select> options binded by ngModel

Tags: angular, angular5

My select box is this.

```
<select class="custom-select" [(ngModel)]="settings[0].isPrivate">
<option [value]="Y">Yes</option>
<option [value]="N">No</option>
</select>
```

`settings[0].isPrivate` is `ENUM ('Y', 'N')`.

I want the select box to set *No* to default is the value is 'N', or *Yes* if the value is 'Y'

Currently, when the page load, the default value is blank. If I selected a value(Yes or No) and console log it via button, I get undefined values.

Comment: Your options values ARE undefined, since you're trying to bind them to Y and N component properties. Use quotes like so; `<option [value]="'Y'">Yes</option>`

Comment: Check whether you initialized "settings" variable. It might be possible that, on first page load, you haven't assigned any value to "settings" variable and then you are programmatically assigning it in probably ngOnInit. In that case, it will always be undefined at first page load.

Comment: Thanks ritaj. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `[value]` should be encolsed with quotes if it is a string

try this

```
<select class="custom-select" [(ngModel)]="settings[0].isPrivate">
<option [value]="'Y">Yes</option>
<option [value]="'N'">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: is it any different ffrom the comment in the answer